# Microsoft. Graph OnlineMeeting Get Status And Force Termination

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm developing a system to generate web meeting URL and manage it's.
And the number of managing URL is more than 200 URL.

1. Is it possible to get the status of whether a guest or someone is participating in the online meeting of the calendar created in using API?
2. Is it possible to forcibly terminate the online meeting of the calendar created in using API?
3. Is it possible to send a message to an online meeting of a calendar created in using API?